# Как запустить постоянное обучение бота?

Tags: бот, искусственный-интеллект

Появились идеи создать бота, который будет общаться в соц. сетях в личных сообщениях. Не для коммерческих целей. Просто интересно.

Интересен вопрос, каким образом сделать чтобы он обучался на основе потребляемой информации.

Понятное дело можно придумать какие-то шаблоны и ответы на них, но хотелось бы более умного бота...

В каком направлении идти?

Comment: ого вопросик)) вам нужно обратиться к машинному обучению и нейронным сетям

Answer (score 0):

Может начать с того, что-бы овладеть элементарной компьютерной грамотностью? Ну например, умением САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО что-то искать в Google. Тогда найти вот такие подсказки не составит труда:

https://habr.com/ru/post/262247/

https://habr.com/ru/post/346606/

https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/chatbots.pdf

https://tproger.ru/translations/telegram-bot-create-and-deploy/

https://habr.com/ru/post/317732/

https://habr.com/ru/company/just_ai/blog/412557/

https://khashtamov.com/ru/create-telegram-bot-in-python/

https://habr.com/ru/post/326312/

https://habr.com/ru/post/355014/

https://toster.ru/q/467638

https://ain.ua/2016/04/27/kak-sozdat-bota-7-servisov-kotorye-pomogayut-eto-sdelat/

А вот тут обсуждали аналогичный вопрос почти 11 (!!!) лет назад.

http://www.commfort.com/ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4321